# How can the imperial roman army keep the dinosaurs in check?

Tags: humans, aliens, civilization, dinosaurs

Set in the distance future where alien had seemingly annihilated about 99% of the entire human population including space colonies, the remaining survivors are enslaved for entertainment purposes only.

Soon the alien grown bored so they created a dozen of cloned dinosaurs from the late Cretaceous period and set them to roam freely in the Roman empire via a temporal shift, these dinosaurs will appear simultaneously within a densely populated area.

Comment below should there be any doubt. I've changed from hybrid to clone so these diversity of dinosaurs are the exact copies of their originals, the only difference is the alien have somehow enables the dinosaurs to adapt to the new environment and climate.

My question is how can a battalion of Roman soldiers subdue 1 adult giganotosaurus, 1 adult spinosaurus, 1 pair of adult Tyrannosaurus Rex and 12 dozen of velociraptors during a surprise attack in the middle of the night? Kindly take note the soldiers are taken by surprise and this will be their first and probably only engagement.

Note: No worry these dinosaurs are programmed to hunt only mammals, so don't expect the people of Roman empire to watch a brawl between these ferocious creatures while betting. I'll applaud you if you can keep the human casualties within 2 digit figures within a week.

Comment: I think you're going to have to define more clearly the size and capabilities of these "hybrid carnivorous dinosaurs" for anyone to have a chance of answering in a sensible manner.

Comment: @Steve Bird I've resurrected the original dinosaurs to terrorise ancient civilization.

Comment: Do the Romans have ballistae and scorpios?

Comment: @Bookeater yes of course.

Comment: Note that real velociraptors were about the size of turkeys, not as seen in Jurassic Park if that's what you meant.

Comment: @TravisChristian: I was wondering about that too.   OP: Are the dinos controlled by an intelligence that will make them fight as a unit, or is this basically a bunch of wild animals released into an urban center?

Comment: The Jurassic Park raptors were Utahraptor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utahraptor, not velociraptor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Side A the alien-dropped dinosaurs.**
giganotosaurus 10 tons
spinosaurus 8 tons
tyrannosaurus 15 tons 2x
velociraptor 15kg 144x

**Side B the Romans.**
5 centuries, 5 ballistae and 5 scorpios.

**Setting up the board.**
The dinosaurs will be dropped inside Rome; the gig in the Colosseum, the spino in the Forum and the tyrs on a bridge over the Tiber. The raptors are dropped between the tight-packed insula of the city. Side A will be aggressive and cause panic among the citizens. Side B will be asleep apart from a few guards. Knowing about elephants they will not be hesitant to engage.

**Body count.**
The citizens will flee as best they can. Attacks and panic together will cause at least 50-100 casualties in the first hour. Then the legionnaires will arrive on-site. The commander will detach one century for crowd control, alleviating panic related casualties. Another will be sent out to kill the raptors using javelins.
Three full centuries with all siege weapons will then stake out some cows to lure and kill the tyrs, then the spino and finally the gig. In the end all troops together will finish off the last raptors. Body count among the legionnaires will be some 50% or 250. Body count among the citizens, including any wounded that do not make it will be at least 1000. Slaves are of course not counted at all.

In case the city burns, a sizeable risk, the body count will be thousands more.

Answer (score 7):

The Romans can easily make Caltrops.  Dinos get sore feet, and stay away from Romans.

Comment: I agree with this answer. I do not see why people down vote it, except to say that people are angry that science contradicts popular culture.

Comment: This made me look up "roman caltrops" and yes, the roman *did* know how to make and use caltrops.  Pretty wicked looking ones too. +1

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to play devils advocate here and point out that we may be giving too much credit to stupid extinct animals. Suppose a pack of dinosaurs saw a large unit of Romans marching rank-and-file; what with the barrages of fire arrows, siege weapons, trumpet blowing, war cries and what-not. Who's to say that they wouldn't get scared and scatter off into the woods to live like the wild animals that they are?

Who's to say that they wouldn't just like, kill one person and then start fighting each other over the food? who's to say that they wouldn't just break into a farm, eat one sheep and then lay down and go to sleep? Who's to say that they wouldn't just trip over a fence and die? You know that they lost the natural selection game right?

Answer (score 2):

### **The Dinosaurs are going to have a bad night**

It was standard Roman practice to build [fortifications](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castra) around every camp whenever the legion stopped for the night.

> ...as soon as they have marched into an enemy's land, they do not begin to fight until they have walled their camp about; nor is the fence they raise rashly made, or uneven; nor do they all abide ill it, nor do those that are in it take their places at random; but if it happens that the ground is uneven, it is first leveled: their camp is also four-square by measure, and carpenters are ready, in great numbers, with their tools, to erect their buildings for them.

A fully functional legion and attending camp are very difficult to catch unawares. A castra like this would have guards posted along the walls. Well trained archers would be close at hand.

Attacking a Roman legion at night is actually when they are least vulnerable. A high timber wall will preclude the initial bloodbath perhaps the OP envisioned. When/if the wall is breached, it will have been enough time to organize the troops for defense and counter attack. Most of all, the Romans are highly disciplined and accustomed to difficult circumstances. Depending on what period of Roman history these dinosaurs attack, the Romans may have fought the [elephants of Hannibal](http://www.thehistoryherald.com/Articles/Ancient-History-Civilisation/Hannibal-and-the-Punic-Wars/hannibal-s-elephants-myth-and-reality) and tactics gained from those battles can be easily adapted to fight "two legged elephants".

**Threat analysis:Equivalents**

- Velociraptor: Equivalent to mounted calvary with only melee weapons.
- Gigantosaur and others: These are two legged elephants. Perhaps faster but still a melee only attacker.

**Casualties**

Romans: A few. The Romans fight these kinds of battles frequently. They are prepared with shields and armor. Their commanders are generally experienced and flexible. The Romans conquered the world for a reason. 
Dinosaurs: All, unless the dinosaurs decide to work on easier prey somewhere else. The Dinosaurs also don't have armor of any kind other than their skin. They can also be baited with cow carcasses then trapped or picked off.

Sorry, dinosaurs. You lose.